# Java 8 ConcurrentHashMap merge vs computeIfAbsent

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, merge, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I'm working exercises from the book "Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient" by Cay S. Horstmann. There're 2 exercises that ask for different implementations of the same algorithm, one using `merge`, the other `computeIfAbsent`. I've implemented the program using `merge` but can't figure out how to use `computeIfAbsent` to do the same thing. It seems to me that `computeIfPresent` would be a better fit, because `merge` only works if the key is present and so does `computeIfPresent`.

Problem statement:

> Write an application in which multiple threads read all words from a
>   collection of files. Use a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<File>>` to
>   track in which files each word occurs. Use the `merge` method to update
>   the map.

My code using `merge`:

```
public static Map<String, Set<File>> reverseIndexUsingMerge(final Path path)
        throws IOException {
    final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<File>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    final BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Set<File>> action = (key,
        value) -> map.merge(key, value, (existingValue, newValue) -> {
        LOGGER.info("Received key: {}, existing value: {}, new value: {}.",
            key, existingValue, newValue);

        newValue.addAll(existingValue);

        return newValue;
    });

    commonPool().invokeAll(
        find(path, 1,
            (p, fileAttributes) -> fileAttributes.isRegularFile())
            .map(p -> new ReverseIndex(p, action))
            .collect(toList()));

    return unmodifiableMap(map);
}

private static class ReverseIndex implements Callable<Void> {
    private final Path p;
    private final BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Set<File>> action;

    private static final Pattern AROUND_WHITESPACE = compile("\\s");

    private ReverseIndex(final Path p,
        final BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Set<File>> action) {
        this.p = p;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        reverseIndex().forEach(action);

        return null;
    }

    private Map<String, Set<File>> reverseIndex() {
        /* File stream needs to be closed. */
        try (Stream<String> lines = lines(p, UTF_8)) {
        return lines.flatMap(AROUND_WHITESPACE::splitAsStream)
            .collect(
                groupingBy(String::toString,
                    mapping(word -> p.toFile(), toSet())));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Something went wrong. Get the hell outta here.",
            e);

        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on what have to be done, *if the value is absent*. What you have to do, is to create a new `Set` value for the absent entry. Of course, if you use an operation which has an atomicity guaranty for the *creation* of the `Set` only, adding to the `Set` will happen concurrently, which requires using a concurrent `Set`. You can utilize a `ConcurrentHashMap` to create a de-facto `ConcurrentHashSet` (which doesn’t exist in that form) by mapping to a fixed value, which is especially simple if you let the value signalling presence be `Boolean.TRUE`:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<File>> map=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
final BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Set<File>> action =
    (key, value) -> map.computeIfAbsent(key, x->ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet())
                       .addAll(value);
```

Comment: How does this handle the case when the key is already present and values need to be merged (same word present in 2 separate files)? `computeIfAbsent` executes only for missing keys.

Comment: The `addAll` call will always be performed, regardless of whether the `Set` was newly created or already existing. It’s part of your `BiConsumer`, not of the function passed to `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: From the Javadoc, `computeIfAbsent` returns "the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null". So it always returns something, that's the part I was missing.
The exercise also asks how's it better than the `merge`. I don't see any benefit though.

Comment: The merge operation runs exclusively for the particular key, blocking all other threads which want to merge with the same key, while in the `computeIfAbsent` variant the `addAll` can run concurrently. Assuming that the threads will add different files to the `Set`, this might improve the throughput, given how the Java 8 implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` works (i.e. all distinct keys can be `put` without contention).

Answer (score 1):

I used `computeIfAbsent` and filter files by extension ".txt".
The results are displayed in the console. 
For IntelliJ IDEA IDE: if the result is incomplete, then check and increase "Override console cycle buffer size" (File/Settings/Editor/General/Console).

Import list:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
```

My solve this task:

```
public static void printMap(Path path){
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(path)){
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<File>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            stream.parallel()
                    .filter(p -> !(Files.isDirectory(p)) & p.getFileName()
                            .toString()
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .endsWith(".txt"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .forEach((p) -> {
                        try {
                            Files.lines(p, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                    .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("\\PL+")).stream())
                                    .filter(w -> w.length() > 0)
                                    .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                    .parallel()
                                    .forEach(
                                            key -> {
                                                Set<File> tempSet = new HashSet<>();
                                                tempSet.add(new File(p.toString()));
                                                map.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet())
                                                        .addAll(tempSet);
                                            });
                        } catch (IOException e){
                        } catch (UncheckedIOException e){}
                    });

            map.entrySet().stream()
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e){}
    }
```

For call `printMap()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Path path = Paths.get(*somePathName*);
        printMap(path);
    }
```

If need use `merge`, then just replace

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()).addAll(tempSet);
```

to

```
map.merge(key, tempSet, (oldSet, newSet) -> {oldSet.addAll(newSet); return oldSet;});
```